# is it necessary to define a template in a separate file?

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-templating

Is it possible to compose a template defined in the same file, like the following.  Or is it required that the composed template be contained in a separate file?

```
<template>
    <template name=myTemplate" bindable="instance">
        $(instance.someText}
    </template>

    <div with.bind="instance">
        <compose view="myTemplate" model="instance"/>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36191678/aurelia-inline-definition-of-html-only-custom-element

Comment: @JeremyDanyow that only seems to be possible when you use SystemJS. Is there any way to make it work with aurelia-cli?

Comment: @JeremyDanyow It seems that solution only works if one includes the associated javascript.  Am I correct?

I'm not interested in using that solution, as it looks too fragile.  I would much rather see a solution that is built into Aurelia.

Comment: @FredKleuver yes, the system.register would change to something like require.define

Comment: @DougKent correct, understandable- remaining options are: use separate files or request enhancement (or even better... send PR)

Comment: @JeremyDanyow Enhancement is already requested, [here](https://github.com/aurelia/templating/issues/473)  :-)